# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.DeleteFromTable in Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, delta-lake, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to use the method `.delete()` to remove one record from a delta table as follows:

```
val my_dt = : DeltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(ss, my_delta_path)
my_dt.delete("pk= '123456'")
```

When I run my code in Intellij I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.DeleteFromTable.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/LogicalPlan;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;)V
    at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.$anonfun$executeDelete$1(DeltaTableOperations.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError$(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.improveUnsupportedOpError(DeltaTable.scala:42)
    at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.executeDelete(DeltaTableOperations.scala:41)
    at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.executeDelete$(DeltaTableOperations.scala:41)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.executeDelete(DeltaTable.scala:42)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.delete(DeltaTable.scala:183)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.delete(DeltaTable.scala:172)
```

I read that the issues is I need to pass the following two parameters:

```
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

So I tried to pass them in several different ways without success:

First when building the spark session:

```
val ss = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
      .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()
```

Also as program parameters in Intellij itself:

[image]

Besides, in the pom I added the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
        <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
        <artifactId>delta-storage</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However the exception is still there. What am I missing?

As additional info, I am able to write and read delta tables in my local system without issues using:

```
my_df.write
    .format("delta")
    .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save(my_path)

val my_dt : DeltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(ss, my_path)
```

Comment: what is the Spark version?

Comment: @AlexOtt spark version 3.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spark 3.2.x you need to use Delta 2.0.x, or to use Delta 2.1.x you need to upgrade to Spark 3.3.x.  Check [releases page](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html) for Spark/Delta compatibility matrix.